# If I want to read document files like .doc, .docx, .pdf files. Which permission will work for Android 13?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-13

Permissions

These permissions are not working for Andoird 13. I want to read document files like .doc, .docx, .pdf, .ppt etc all type of document files.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
    }
} else {
    loadFiles();
}
```

I have provided the problem and I expecting to fix the issue. Which permissions will work for Android 13?

Comment: `These permissions are not working for Andoird 13.` ?? Which permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong question.

Permissions to read non media files do not depend on file type or file extension.

Your question does not make sense.